Can't display images on Github Pages Vite + React
I've spend hours trying to fix an error, but nothing helped. I've transfered my local react project to github pages and everything works except images. They are not loading and give 404 error in the console, at the same time exact same code works perfectly on local server.
I import image from the img folder directly to the jsx file, after I run npm run build  I also get the file in dist folder. Vite config file uses the correct name of the repository as its base.
Before that I've tried moving 'assets' folder to 'public' folder and then using src={${import.meta.env.BASE_URL}assets/imgs/tatsumi1-img1.jpg}, but that wasn't working either.
My repository: https://github.com/nneia/Shutoku-Updates
JSX File where I import image: https://github.com/nneia/Shutoku-Updates/blob/master/src/components/ListContainer/ListContainer.jsx
Image location: https://github.com/nneia/Shutoku-Updates/blob/master/src/assets/imgs/tatsumi1-img1.jpg
Please help!

Update the base URL in your Vite Config:
export default {
 base: '/Shutoku-Updates/',
}

Import the image with correct path:
import tatsumiImg from '../../assests/img/tatsumi1-img1.jpg';

<img src={tatsumiImg} alt='img'/>


It is the same way you have described, but nothing still works(

check your vite.config.js
it has base path as "/Shutoku-Updates/"
so, while build and deplpoyement , it will pick bath path from "/Shutoku-Updates/".
its best practice to give base path as "src" or you need to adjust your path
in  ListContainer.jsx file.

Thanks, it is the same way base: "/Shutoku-Updates/" and inside jsx file its like this: import tatsumi from "../../assets/imgs/tatsumi1-img1.jpg".  Images still not being loaded tho :(
